# How Does One Deploy a Jersey Application to a Remote Tomcat Server

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, jersey

I need to state up front that I am not a Java developer. So it is fair to assume that I know very little about the tooling etc. that Java dev's will be naturally familiar with.

So, I have created a Jersey web api (2.25.1) on my home server running Windows 2012. It serves data to a Xamarin application. I need to deploy this to a Linux server (Ubuntu) on AWS which my friend spun up.

At the moment, the only access I have is via SSH (Putty).

Tomcat (and Glassfish) have been installed on the Linux machine.

How do I go about deploying that application to that AWS server?

The official Jersey documentation seems to be MIA, and my Googling efforts don't yield much. There's a lot of SO questions with a similar title to this one. But I have not found any of the answers (and in many cases, questions) helpful to my cause.

Cheers

Comment: Use sftp to transfer files to a remote server over SSH.

Comment: Use scp to transfer files to a remote server over SSH

Comment: Where do I put them, on the server? And which files. Where does Spring STS dump  its deployment files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are using maven to create your jersey web app .
Upon build you will get a *.war file .Copy the same to tomcat/webapps folder .
Start your tomcat then.

To take your file there on remote use winscp tool with your ssh credentials.

Comment: I figured out how to create a war file using the Export feature of Spring STS. I was able to get it working on the proper Tomcat installation on my local machine. Got the data coming down the pipe. Last task is to get it onto the AWS server. Thanks.